# Sub query performance vs join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have number of table with thousands records called Assessment which assosiated with more than 1 records in Assessment_Review.
It took a lot of time when I retrieved assessment review result from Assessment table with join function, but it did a better job when I using sub query.

Is it okay to used sub query for some issue like this?I had read so many article that join is way better than sub query in performance for big data, but I found it different in my case. Or maybe my data isn't big enough to have performance issue by using sub query?

Comment: Can you provide clarity and context to your question with examples of your queries utilising join and sub-query?

Comment: Provide the queries and their explain plans if you want an explanation of performance differences

Comment: Joins are often better than subqueries.  Sometimes, subqueries perform better.

Comment: There are many issues here -- a general statement can't be made -- It depends on many things.  I'd be able to tell you why if I could see your actual data model and execution plans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's faster, do it!  With SQL tuning, actual performance is ALWAYS the best thing to go with no matter what conventional wisdom says.  I would use the join before subquery rule of thumb to write a SQL select in the first place, but never hold to it if a subquery provides a faster result.

As a side note, finding a way to tell the dbms how to get a small subset of rows first will often lead to better performance.  Say you have one table a with 10,000 rows and table b with 100,000 rows.  You only want things in table a where they equal a subset of table b.  If you can use a subquery or a with statement to limit the size of table b to something much smaller, say 1,000 rows, and THEN tell the database to join to table a, you'll be in much better shape.  In other words, limit first, then join.

One more thing, be careful about optimizing queries in development databases that have small data sets...you might find what was fast in dev to be really slow in production when it has significantly more data.  This is the only time I can think of where it would be better to go with a rule of thumb instead of actual performance.

Answer (score -1):

There's a test in [this article](http://www.chrislondon.co/joins-vs-subqueries/) that actually results in a suggestion to use subqueries **in the FROM clause** rather than using solely JOINs (and rather than using them in the WHERE clause). This seems to be basically right, but however, it's a very complex issue and should be reconsidered everytime you face performance issues.

Edit: The article is refering MySQL, thanks for putting it right. However, I think that the conclusion, that you need to check both options in your particular situation, is the same. I found a few articles regarding SQL Server (for example [this one](http://sqlstudies.com/2013/05/02/comparing-an-inner-join-vs-a-subquery/)), and I finished it with the same conclusion.

Comment: This article is about MySQL which has an optimization engine very different than every other major vendor.  **AND CERTAINLY** can't compare to SQL Server which is tagged in the question

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer. Thanks for making me notice.